# Why does Internet Explorer 11 Tracking Protection Not Block Certain Requests

Tags: internet-explorer, tracking

I have an IE 11 tracking protection list with the following filter: `- .com/c.gif?`  But when I go to www.msn.com, for example, I see a bunch of POST requests to `http://otf.msn.com/c.gif?` that appear to be going through successfully.  Any thoughts on why?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think it may be because according to the tracking protection list protocol, otf.msn.com is not considered a third party with respect to www.msn.com.  So the filter is not applied to oft.msn.com requests when visiting www.msn.com.